# Play sound in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, audio, electron

I'm working on an `Electron app` with Angular 4. I want to play sound on some specific action. Is there any module or code for that? It can be in the angular 4 or if electron is providing some service for that it should also work

As I want to play it on some action I can't use the HTML audio tag and audio() of javascript

I only want to play the sound of 2-3 seconds so no other functionalities are needed.

It can be of electron or Angular 4 any of them can work...

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-music-player-with-angular-2-electron-i-setup-basics-concepts

Answer (score 116, accepted):

just did this in a project am working (angular 4) and it worked

```js
playAudio(){
  let audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = "../../../assets/audio/alarm.wav";
  audio.load();
  audio.play();
}
this.playAudio();
```

make sure the path is correct and references an existing audio

Comment: I am getting error - he play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

Comment: sorry, its firefox setting issue. Had to enable

Comment: It isn't works on IOS, Maybe you know answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73625851/how-to-play-audio-in-safari-ios-angular

Answer (score 51):

As per Robin's comment, i have checked that link we can use it using the audio() object in the ts file like this:

```js
this.audio = new Audio();
this.audio.src = "../../../assets/sounds/button_1.mp3";
this.audio.load();
this.audio.play();
```

Comment: How to change volume in this method?

Comment: @carte // set the volume at 50%
this.audio.volume = 0.5; 
this.audio.load();
this.audio.play();

Answer (score 34):

updated: 
I had the same problem and used ViewChild reference with ElementRef to solve this.

app.component.ts

```js
@ViewChild('audioOption') audioPlayerRef: ElementRef;

onAudioPlay(){
  this.audioPlayerRef.nativeElement.play();
}
```

app.component.html

```html
   <audio #audioOption>
       <source src='../*.mp3' type="audio/mp3">
   </audio>
```

Comment: From angular this was the only solution that worked for me

Comment: Is there any way to do it dynamically ? I mean replacing src by a variable

Comment: the angular way , you can either do [src]='"path_to_to_your_audio"' or
src='{{path_to_your_audio}} then in your component 
assign the path_to_to_your_audio dynamically

Answer (score 10):

You could try using [howler.js](https://howlerjs.com/)
You can install it to your project with `npm install --save howler` and play a sound like this:

```js
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['sound.mp3']
});

sound.play();
```

Comment: Howler handles audio on mobile browsers too as this needs to be 'unlocked' by user interaction. Solved me issue !!

Comment: It's not working! I have this message:  howler.js:2432 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio

Answer (score 9):

step 1 npm install --save howler

step 2 import Howl from howler in component

step3 : inside the functional block add below code

```
         let sound = new Howl({
          src: ['sound.mp3']
            });

         sound.play()
```

Answer (score 6):

**Angular 13:**

Create a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AudioService {

  constructor() { }

  playAudio(): void {
    const audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = '../../../assets/audio/alert.wav';
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }
}
```

Then in your component:

```
[...]

import { AudioService } from '../services/audio.service';
[...]

  constructor(
    private audioService: AudioService
  ){
    // Here or anywhere else
    this.audioService.playAudio();
}
```

Comment: I don't see why use a service if you do all the logic (both the loading and the playing) inside the playAudio() method. The method should be then called loadAndPlay()

Answer (score 4):

```
playSound(sound) {
    sound = "../assets/sounds/" + sound + ".mp3";
    sound && ( new Audio(sound) ).play()
  }
```

Where `sound` is the file name if you need this method to be reusable.

Answer (score 3):

The Asmon code is good, but I think that the real problem is that the Google Chrome policy was updated, on this page https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio  you can find The answer In summary, the focus should be on this.

Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:

Muted autoplay is always allowed.

**Autoplay with sound is allowed if:**

User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).

On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously play video with sound.

On mobile, the user has [added the site to their home screen].

Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

Comment: I find this possible solution and work for me without problems
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/audio-autoplay-not-working-in-chrome