# How to play audio in safari ios angular

Tags: ios, angular, safari

I have this code:

```
  public playAudio(pathToFile: string): void {
    const audio = new Audio();
    audio.autoplay = true;
    audio.src = `${environment.serverUrl}/${pathToFile}`;
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }
```

It treggered by button click, something like this:

```
<button class="btn-pronounce"
        (click)="playAudio(pathToFile)">
</button>
```

It works fine in chrome and firefox but in safari it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 1):

One of desicion is using this library: https://github.com/rserota/wad

Code still almost the same:

```
import Wad from 'web-audio-daw';

 public playAudio(pathToFile: string): void {
    const bell = new Wad({source: `${environment.serverUrl}/pronunciation-files/{pathToFile}`});
    bell.play();
    bell.stop();
  }
```

But it isn't work in Angualr universal, because this library using windows.